# Flex builder "Refreshing workspace" and "Building workspace" over and over

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

Facing one problem with Flex builder "Refreshing workspace" and "Building workspace"  over and over... Am wasting almost 10min on every build. running FB 3 on my win 7 , 64 bit , 3 gig Ram.

[image]

Comment: Have you turned off "Build Automatically" in you project settings?
If you don't, every time you save a file the build process will be triggered. Ten minutes is really a long time though. Check your eclipse.ini of your FB instance to see if it has the correct memory settings.

Comment: I have been spending almost 3 days on the internet and tried this option too no luck at all.

Comment: Also the more projects you have in an 'open' state at a time, the more memory is consumed. Certainly with Flash projects (as opposed to Java projects). Only keep the projects open that you're working on. And as Dennis suggests: you may have 3gb of RAM; FB is a Java app and runs in a VM that gets only 500mb by default.

Comment: Somewhere I read cleaning the project will help but its not true and also I read deleting ".metadata" folder and restart the FB.Did that too but no improvement at all , now my workspace contains only one project. This issue driving me crazy , I never had this sort of issues before on my past 3 years. These problems am facing after switching my OS to windows 7. If anyone have any idea about opensource Flex IDE it would be great help. No actually I fed up and trying to setup Eclipse classic for running my Flex projects.

Comment: Is your JRE a 64-bit version?

Comment: yes its 64-bit , however am trying to re install again.

Comment: I think FB standalone comes with a packaged JRE. I'd go with barebones Eclipse install and FB plugin and make sure it uses the right JRE. If you have another 32-bit JRE installed (perhaps a Java server) Eclipse might be using that instead of the 64-bit JRE.

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't care if the application consumes too much memory, I just want it to compile. I have to clean up the project several times until it compliles. This happens a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from everything mentioned, the general architecture of your application might end up being the reason why in your case is slow while others it's not an issue. Your main mxml that contains mx:Application (or whatever else they call it these days) might have children whose children [embed] a lot of others things. [Embed]-ing assets involves transcoding those bitmaps and mp3 sound clips into swf which can add to a lengthy compilation experience.

If you have like $60 bucks lying around, you could try out Clement Wong's Hellfire Compiler daemon. Dude is one of the smartest unsung persons in the industry. If you have a multi-core CPU, it will divy up the compilation work and get your binaries done quicker.

[HellFire Compiler Daemon at Bytecode Workshop](http://bytecode-workshop.com/)